# Convert protected XLSB file to XLSX. Golang

Tags: go, xlsx, xlsb

I have a microservice running Golang that scrapes emails from my suppliers and saves the attachments.

One supplier sends their invoice data in a protected XLSB file.

I need to open that file and split up the different sheets into seperate files in order to upload the data into my system. To do this I can use the "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2" package.

Unfortunately, Excelize does not support XLSB files, hence I need to convert the file into XLSX first.

I am stuggling to find a package that will do this.

Alternatively, if there is another language that could do this and I can embed that code within my GO code, that could work.

Any help would be much appreciated.